# Queueing Workflow?

Tags: workflow

I am creating a list to use as a queue. I am wondering if there is a way to write a workflow that would notify a user when they person ahead of them in the list has completed their item?

I am using SharePoint 2013 and I have SharePoint Designer.

My current column structure is:
1. ID#
2. User Name- people picker
3. Status- drop down (In Queue, Active, Complete)

Is there a way to write a workflow that when Status is equal to Complete it emails the User from the next item in the list. When item #1 has a status of complete it emails the person in the user name column of item #2?

Comment: Please elaborate what do you mean by the person ahead.paste you column structure

Comment: My current column structure is:
1. ID# 
2. User Name- People Picker 
3.Status- In Queue, Active, Complete

My thought is can a workflow run when the Status column equals complete and look at the next item on the list and email that User to let them know the queue is open for them?

Answer (score 0):

You can make a workflow with trigger 'when item updated', with steps:

1. Condition: is Status == 'completed' ? if no end, else go to next step
2. find the next item, 
   something like: get items with id greater than actual item id, order by id ascending
3. get the user of the first element from step 2
4. email him

Comment: Thank you for your help. I'm struggling with finding an action in Designer that would complete step 2?

Comment: you can use HTTP Request:

/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('{ListName}')/items?$filter=Id gt {actualId}&$orderby=Id asc